# Match lists to parts of a list and return non-matched tokens

Tags: java, list, parsing

I've been tasked with creating a linter for a filtering language used by a vendor.

An example filter would be:

```
({HL7:MSH.21-1} != 'ADT')
and
({HL7:MSH.4-1} != 'TRI')
    and
(
or ({HL7:MSH.21-1} == 'LAB')
    or ({HL7:MSH.21-1} == 'RAD')
    or ({HL7:MSH.21-1} == 'TRN')
)
```

I have successfully split it into tokens:

```
[$, (, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, !=, ', ADT, ', ), $, and, $, (, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 4, -, 1, }, !=, ', TRI, ', ), $, and, $, (, $, or, (, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', LAB, ', ), $, or, (, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', RAD, ', ), $, or, (, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', TRN, ', ), $, )]
```

With `$` symbolizing new lines.

I also have it blocking on parentheses and brackets:

```
[(, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, !=, ', ADT, ', )]
[{, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }]
[(, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 4, -, 1, }, !=, ', TRI, ', )]
[{, HL7, :, MSH, ., 4, -, 1, }]
[(, $, or, (, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', LAB, ', ), $, or, (, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', RAD, ', ), $, or, (, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', TRN, ', ), $, )]
[(, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', LAB, ', )]
[{, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }]
[(, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', RAD, ', )]
[{, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }]
[(, {, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }, ==, ', TRN, ', )]
[{, HL7, :, MSH, ., 21, -, 1, }]
```

The problem is, some things are not included in parentheses or brackets, therefore get excluded from blocks.

Ex: *and*

I need a way to compare the blocks with the full token list and return what isn't in any of them.

Best thing I could think of was to somehow compare all the small lists to the big list and find matches, whatever isn't matched gets pulled, but I have no clue how to go about that.